# PHP preg_split both slashes

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-split

I have a string like this: `"C:\Users\Jamie/Desktop/Test.TXT"`

I want to use `preg_split` to split the string into an array like this, using this code:

```
$arr = preg_split("/(\\|\/)/", "C:\Users\Jamie/Desktop/Test.TXT");
```

What I expect is:

```
array(0=>"C:",1=>"Users",2=>"Jamie",3=>"Desktop",4=>"Test.TXT")
```

But what I got is

```
array(0=>"C:\Users\Jamie/Desktop/Test.TXT")
```

How can I get the expected result using `preg_split`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
$parts = preg_split('~[\\\\/]~', $filename);
```

The `~` are just delimiters. Regular expressions can use pretty much any delimiter. So, instead of `/.../` you can do `~...~`.

When working with backslashes you have to double-escape them, like `\\\\`. To the regular expression engine they will come out as `\\`. In other words, both backslashes in `\\` need to be escaped, hence the `\\\\`.

You can also use the following, if you prefer.

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\\\\\/]/', $filename);
```

Edit. It is a little confusing. Maybe this will explain it in another way:

- In PHP `\\\\` is seen as two escaped backslashes, i.e. `\\`.
- To Regex engine `\\` is seen as one escaped backslash, i.e. `\`.

Comment: I understand the middle part. The question is, what are the `~`s?

Comment: Sverri - please explain the solution, rather than just providing one. thanks. WHY does this work?

Comment: I found out them. All delimiters. Why have I forgotten about the `[]` group?

Comment: @Martin It is common for people to give quick answers, and then improve the answer in the following minutes. Not everyone improves their answers, so it may be a good idea to prompt for an explanation, but you should wait for a bit before doing so ;)

Comment: fair enough, but I am not to know you intend to edit your answer. Pleased you added some more info for OP :)

Comment: Thanks! I understand everything, and the tilde was just used so that the `/` does not need to be escaped again.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) *"A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character"*. Attempting to use `a` as delimiter triggers an warning: **PHP Warning:  preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash**

Comment: @axiac I was wrong, you are right. I removed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace one kind of slashes (backslashes `\` f.e.) with the other kind of slashes (`/`) using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) then use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string:

```
$pieces = explode('/', str_replace('\\', '/', "C:\Users\Jamie/Desktop/Test.TXT"));
print_r($pieces);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:
    [1] => Users
    [2] => Jamie
    [3] => Desktop
    [4] => Test.TXT
)
```

Sure, this solution does not improve your knowledge about `regex` but it is fast and the intent of the code is more clear for the reader.

Comment: This is acceptable, but however, is it a bit too long?